# How to stay on current fragment after progressdialog dismiss android

Tags: java, android

Since we knew that progressdialog need a parameter context or get the activity of fragment but after dismissig the dialog it went to the other fragment which i set the the mainactivity default fragment is homepage

This is the method use in my class

```
 public void UploadProfilePicture(Context context, Uri imageUri){
      ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(context);
 }
```

Comment: Why does it need to close this question? any comment ?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange behavior. If you are inside the Fragment and you want to initialize a Dialog just pass the context of the Fragement.

```
ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(requireContext());
```

Comment: So what would be the proper paramater ? BecauseI use a class of progressdialog and pass parameter `Context context` so it should be `context.requireContext()`?

Comment: If you are inside an activity inside and are initializing ProgressDialog then you will need to do this: `ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(this);`
Otherwise if you are inside a class that extends the Fragment class you will have to do this: `ProgressDialog prog = new ProgressDialog(requireContext());` If this solution is not suitable I ask you if you can tell me how you initialize the `context` variable.

Comment: Still the same it goes back to homepage

Comment: How so you initialize the context variable?

Comment: Ok then I ask you when you invoke the UploadProfilePicture method how do you define the context variable you pass? Are we inside Activity or a Fragment?`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;
    }
}`